# How to show a PopupWindow in another PopupWindow?

Tags: android, popupwindow

I need to show a PopupWindow B in another PopupWindow A and B's anchor is one of widgets in A.I got the exception below :

> > AndroidRuntime(888):
> >     android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRoot$W@44ef1b68 is not valid; is your activity running?

Can help me? thanks.

Comment: If you can show your code, I might can help you.

Comment: What do you mean by PopupWindow? A dialog?

Comment: Any leads on this one? I wish to obtain the same thing too

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue also, can only try a alternative way to display a transparent dialog activity instead of parent popupwindow.